# ASP .NET MVC cannot upload image to Blob Storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to upload an image to a Blob Container in Microsoft Storage Account.

Here is the code from Controller where i try to create a new announce on my web application.

imageService.UploadImageAsync(photo); is working, i tryied this on another example just to verify if is correct  and it`s working

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(AdViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            CreateAd(model.Title,
                model.Description,
                model.Location);
            return RedirectToAction("ViewAds");

        }

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(HttpPostedFileBase photo)
    {
        var imageUrl = await imageService.UploadImageAsync(photo);
        TempData["LatestImage"] = imageUrl.ToString();
        return View();
    }
```

Here is the view for Create.cshtml

### Create

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Ad", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>AdViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Ad", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Photo">Photo</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="file" name="photo" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </fieldset>

        }

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

After i hit the Create button in the browser, the ad is created in database, but the image is not uploaded in my Blob Container from Storage Account.
I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You're nesting forms and that's not good. You can't make 2 post requests at the same time. And actually, there is no need to split requests and you need to merge create and upload actions in one. Smth like that:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(AdViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        CreateAd(model.Title,
            model.Description,
            model.Location);
        return RedirectToAction("ViewAds");

    }

   var imageUrl = await imageService.UploadImageAsync(photo);
    TempData["LatestImage"] = imageUrl.ToString();

  
    return View();
}
```

And the view:
Remove Html.BeginForm("Upload"...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Ad", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>AdViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

            <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Photo">Photo</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="file" name="photo" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </fieldset>



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help!
In the meantime, i've maked some modifications and now it works.
I want to ask you if I can make some improvements to my code. Should i make a single ActionResult from Create and Upload ?
Also, *counter* variable help me when i save image, to rename the image. Should i declare *counter* in Controller, or in *imageService.UploadImageAsync()* method ?

```
string imageName = "id-" + AdProcessor.GetLastId() + "-img-nr-" + counter + Path.GetExtension(imageToUpload.FileName);
```

This is the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(AdViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase[] photo)
    {
        await Upload(photo);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            CreateAd(model.Title,
                model.Description,
                model.Location);


            return RedirectToAction("ViewAds");

        }

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task Upload(HttpPostedFileBase[] photo)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (var img in photo)
        {
            counter++;
            var imageUrl = await imageService.UploadImageAsync(img, counter);
           // AdProcessor.SaveImageData(Int32.Parse(AdProcessor.GetLastId()), imageUrl);
        }
    }
```

Here is my View:

### Create

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Ad", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>AdViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Photo">Photo</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="file" name="photo" multiple />
                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is designed as a FAQ-style database of easy to understand "question->answer" pairs. You are asking another question in an answer but nobody will look for your new question asked in an answer. Experts who are willing to help usually filter out answered questions so your question drops out of theirs search because it is already answered. And they certainly will not look into answers. [Use this button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) when you want to ask a new question otherwise be ready your question will never be answered